# Adding labels to a Dask graph

Tags: graphviz, dask, dask-delayed

Default graph.visualize() function does not display task labels. Is there any way they can be added manually using `graph = dask.delayed()(tasks)`?

I need the labels to show basic business logic (which tables are joined with which etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a filename to the `visualize` method with a `.dot` extension.  Dask will then write out the result as a text file in the DOT language.  You could then modify this file and add labels manually.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)